# Multiply two hexadecimal values

Tags: java, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

I've written an algorithm which can multiply two hex values and return a hex as a result. What do you think about the below solution?

```
package com.datastructute.arraystring;

public class hexadecimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(multiplyHex("AE08FE2111111111", "BF"));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("DF", "BC"));        // A3C4
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("ADF398", "BA48"));  // 7e93e8f2c0

        // Test Screnarios
        System.out.println(multiplyHex(null, null));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("  ", "  "));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("hyh", "hyhy"));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("abyh", "ashyhy"));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("-1-1-1", "-1-1-1"));
        System.out.println(multiplyHex("AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE21111111111111AE08FE2111111111AE08FE21111111111111AE08FE21111AE08FE211111111111111", "AE0AE08FE21111111118FE2111111111AE08FE2111111111")); 
    }

    public static String multiplyHex(String str1, String str2)  {
        if(str1 == null || str2 == null)
            return "Null values are not accepted.";

        char[] hex1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] hex2 = str2.toCharArray();

        int[][] ArrHexMatrix;
        int arrLength = hex1.length + hex2.length;
        int arrIndexLength = hex1.length + hex2.length - 1;
        int lines = hex2.length;
        ArrHexMatrix = new int[hex2.length][arrLength];

        int mod = 0;
        int carry = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = lines - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            carry = 0;
            count = 0;
            for (int j = hex1.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                try {
                    if(getInt(hex2[i])==-1 || getInt(hex1[j])==-1)
                        return "Wrong chracter";

                    mod = (getInt(hex2[i]) * getInt(hex1[j]) + carry) % 16;
                    carry = ((getInt(hex2[i]) * getInt(hex1[j])) + carry) / 16;

                    if (j == 0) {
                        ArrHexMatrix[index][arrIndexLength - count - index] = mod;
                        ArrHexMatrix[index][arrIndexLength - count - 1 - index] = carry;
                    } else {
                        ArrHexMatrix[index][arrIndexLength - count - index] = mod;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                count++;
            }
            index++;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        mod = 0;
        carry = 0;
        count = 0;

        char[] total = new char[arrLength];
        for (int i = arrLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++) {
                sum += ArrHexMatrix[j][i];
            }
            mod = (sum + carry) % 16;
            carry = (sum + carry) / 16;

            try {
                total[i] = getChar(mod);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(total);
    }

    private static int getInt(char chr) {
        switch (chr) {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;
        case 'A':
            return 10;
        case 'B':
            return 11;
        case 'C':
            return 12;
        case 'D':
            return 13;
        case 'E':
            return 14;
        case 'F':
            return 15;
        default:
            return -1;
        }

    }

    private static char getChar(int val) throws Exception {
        switch (val) {
        case 0:
            return '0';
        case 1:
            return '1';
        case 2:
            return '2';
        case 3:
            return '3';
        case 4:
            return '4';
        case 5:
            return '5';
        case 6:
            return '6';
        case 7:
            return '7';
        case 8:
            return '8';
        case 9:
            return '9';
        case 10:
            return 'A';
        case 11:
            return 'B';
        case 12:
            return 'C';
        case 13:
            return 'D';
        case 14:
            return 'E';
        case 15:
            return 'F';
        default:
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `getInt` and `getChar` methods are very long and cumbersome, they can be replaced by this:

Using arrays:

```
private char[] values = new char[]{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
      '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

char getInt(int i) {
    return values[i];
}
```

Java has already built-in methods to do this conversion though, so all that is needed is really:

```
int getInt(char chr) {
    return Character.digit(chr, 16);
}

char getChar(int val) {
    return Character.forDigit(val, 16);
}
```

Hexadecimal values are often showed in lower-case, personally I like that better because it makes it easier to separate the characters (a-f) from the digits (0-9). If you still want to use upper-case characters though, use this:

```
return Character.toUpperCase(Character.forDigit(val, 16));
```

---

```
    private static char getChar(int val) throws Exception {
```

Don't throw `Exception`, use `IllegalArgumentException` instead. `IllegalArgumentException` is a `RuntimeException` and therefore does not need to be caught (or declared in the `throws` declaration), but you are still free to do so if you would like. (Although I would not recommend it)

---

Learn to use [JUnit](http://junit.org) to do the testing.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MultiplyHexTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        assertEquals("A3C4", multiplyHex("DF", "BC"));
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testFailure() {
        multiplyHex("  ", "  ");
    }
}
```

---

`ArrHexMatrix`, being a name for a variable, should start with a lowercase character according to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you Simon, i ll look at junit testing. As you see the time complexity is O(n^2), do you know any better solution for this problem  ?

Comment: @talhakosen The `BigInteger` class also has a `multiply` method with complexity O(n^2), so unfortunately I don't know any faster solution.

Comment: +1 for suggesting JUnit. Reading the console output to verify results is time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: @talhakosen I know there are sub O(n^2) multiplication algoritms... karatsuba comes to mind, http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/78crypto/Karatsuba.java.html has a java implemenation to give an idea on the complexity etc. (wiki page talks about the O complexity

Comment: thanks @Foon, karatsuba has advantages when the length of input > 14.

Answer (score 10):

### Exceptions:

It is common practice to throw an IllegalArgumentException if the input values to a method are not legal. In the sepcific case of null values, there is debate about whether the right response is an IllegalArgumentException, or a NullPointerException. I prefer IllegalArgumentException....

Also, in Java, (and most languages), it is very easy to introduce bugs when making small changes to 1-liner conditionals (just ask apple). When making the changes correctly to 1-liners (without introducing bugs) the actual small changes require adding in braces, so small changes change a lot. In general, use braces, even for 1-liners.

The code:

> ```
>     if(str1 == null || str2 == null)
>         return "Null values are not accepted.";
> ```

Should be:

```
    if(str1 == null || str2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null values are not accepted.");
    }
```

One of the reasons for the exception, by the way, is... consider the following code:

```
System.out.println(multiplyHex("A", multiplyHex("B", null));
```

With your code in the current state, the result will be:

> ```
>    "Wrong chracter"
> ```

Additionally, the "wrong character" message is .... useless. You shoudl have an exception that indicates what the wrong character is:

```
int hxval1 = getInt(hex1[j]);
if (hxval1 < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Illegal character '%s' at position %d in the input value: %s", hex1[j], j, str1));
}
```

Use exceptions

Comment: Thanks rolfl, i got it. As you see the time complexity is O(n^2), do you know any better solution for this problem  ?